# Access Json object from ajax success function

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

this is my JSON object in the controller, I need to access this object from the ajax success function,

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "@Url.Action("Temp","GRN")",
     type: "POST",
     data: { term: request.term },
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data) {
       alert(data.msg);
     }
 });
```

this is my json in controller

```
var Item = new[]
        {
        new  { Item_Name = "Soap", Item_Code = "IT1", Purchase_Price = 10.00, Sell_Price = 20.50},
        new  { Item_Name = "Pen", Item_Code = "IT2", Purchase_Price = 20.00, Sell_Price = 30.00},
        new  { Item_Name = "Paper", Item_Code = "IT3", Purchase_Price = 30.00, Sell_Price = 40.00},
        new  { Item_Name = "Brush", Item_Code = "IT4", Purchase_Price = 40.00, Sell_Price = 50.00}
        };

        return Json(Item);
```

Comment: Life isn't really that hard and does not require so many SO posts. You can use a new-fangled technique called "debugging", which you do with a thing called a "debugger". Put a breakpoint on the line where you're calling `alert` and look at `data`. Chances are good it itself is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @SecondRikudo Looks like anonomous items in C# to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is your `json`.

```
data[0].Item_Name //  "Soap"
data[0].Item_Code  // "IT1"
data[1].Item_Name // "Pen"
```

You can iterate over your data array with a simple for:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++)
{
    var curr = data[i];
    curr.Item_Name; // 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The JSON object is the `data` being passed to the `success` function.

You are alerting `data.msg` which isn't defined, so you'll likely get `undefined` in an alert.

Comment: What do you mean "changed"? What is your goal?

Comment: You didn't mention changing it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an array of data, so you probably want to iterate the result:

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item){
        console.log(item, item.Item_Name); //etc...
    });
}
```